# Check if an event is called if not create another event listener

Tags: node.js, npm, redis, promise

I'm creating a wrapper around the `redis` npm package.

For each method that interacts with the redis client I've come up with a system where it checks if the client is connected. If yes, then continue with the task. If not, return a promise that resolves when the client is connected.

With this approach, I don't have to wait for the redis client to connect to continue.

For example:

```
async clear(){
    if(this.client.connected){
        try {
            await this.client.flushdbAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch(error){
            //error handling stuff
        }
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.client.on("ready", () => {
                resolve(this.clear());
            });
        });
    }
}
```

`this.client` is an instance of `RedisClient` from the `redis` package.

Is this bad practice in terms of efficiency and the number of event listeners it creates every time there is no connection?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Post your question at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as your codes works but you need some improving.

Comment: Reliance on a flag that indicates connection reflects likely bad practice. Functions that initiate db interaction should make a connection, interact (via low level subroutines if necessary), then dispose of the connection. That way, (1) there's never an attempt to interact with the db unless a connection is available and (2) resources are not tied up maintaining connection(s) that are not being used.